# Health zone heals player but I have a problem

Tags: unity

Hello I am creating a special health zone that gives the player health and my current scripts health is going up super fast and I want it to go up by 2 hp per second. How would I do this?

Here is the health zone script.

```
{
    public PlayerHealth playerHealth;
    public float healthGain = 2f;
    
    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (playerHealth.currentHealth < playerHealth.maxHealth)
        {
            playerHealth.currentHealth += (int)healthGain;
            playerHealth.healthBar.SetHealth(playerHealth.currentHealth);
        }

        if (playerHealth.currentHealth >= playerHealth.maxHealth)
        {
            playerHealth.currentHealth = playerHealth.maxHealth;
            playerHealth.healthBar.SetHealth(playerHealth.currentHealth);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to be exactly 2HP once every second or the total amount of HP healed every second is 2HP (Many smaller heals for a total of 2)?

Comment: Unrelated hint: If you turn `PlayerHealth.currentHealth` into a [property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties), then you can move the code for keeping the health between 0 and maxHealth and the code for updating the UI in the `set`-block. That means that you don't have to take care of these things whenever something alters the health of something else. You can just change it like the value of a generic variable and the set-block will take care of everything else that needs to be done when the health changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like to handle health not as `int` but as `float` internally. Because this would allow me to just write this:

```
currentHealth += healthGain * Time.deltaTime;
```

But that does not work with integers, because unless you are dealing with very high values for healthGain, the multiplication with Time.deltaTime will always round it down to 0. So when you want to still use integers for health, then you have to find a different solution. Don't give health on every single FixedUpdate (collision events happen on FixedUpdate, not on Update, by the way). Only give health at regular intervals. Untested code:

```
public PlayerHealth playerHealth;
public float healthInterval = 1f; // one healing action every 1 second
public int healthGain = 2; // 2 HP per healing action
private float healthIntervalLeft = 0f; // time left until next healing action
private bool doHealing = false; // are we on a tick where a healing action should happen?

void FixedUpdate() {
     healthIntervalLeft -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
     if (healthIntervalLeft <= 0f) {
         doHealing = true;
         healthIntervalLeft += healthInterval;
     } else {
         doHealing = false;
     }
}

void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
     if (doHealing) {
          currentHealth += healthGain;
          //...code to clamp the health in the allowed range...
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Now i am going to update the health bar and that should be good thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you are adding the full amount every frame and not taking the actual elapsed time. You need to multiply the health gain per tick by the elapsed frame time before adding it to the player's health. I'm not familiar with unity but I believe it is something like Time.DeltaTime. A search of the unity docs should bring it up.

Also, because you are converting to an int before adding it, you likely won't see any changes at all because the frame time will make the value very small, thus causing the increment value to be rounded to zero. For this reason, you may want to have your player health be a float and only convert it to an int when needed e.g. for displaying in a menu, determining if player is alive, etc.